# Wicket dropdown menu without form - click option redirects to another page

Tags: java, html, drop-down-menu, wicket, hyperlink

I created Select `dropdown menu`. I can create `SelectOptions`, in which I add components, that will be shown in this menu. I am trying to add the links

```
(final Link myLink = new Link("myLink") { ... })
```

into this options, it doesn't work. It just shows names of the links, after clicking the option is selected, but not redirected.

This is example of my HTML code:

`<select wicket:id="projectLinks">
          <option wicket:id="myLink">Create Project</option>
    </select>`

JAVA code:

```
 Select<Link> select = new Select<Link>("projectLinks");

 select.add(new SelectOption<Link>("myLink", new Model(myLink)));
```

Could you provide me any easy example of `DropDown menu` without Form, which options just redirect me to another page after clicking them?

Comment: Google for css or Javascript menus.  the html select tag had other purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an `AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior` to your dropdown to cause the selection to trigger an action, such as page redirection.

```
DropDownChoice projectLinksDropDown = new DropDownChoice("projectLinks", new Model(selectedProjectLink), projectLinkOptionList);
projectLinksDropDown.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onChange") {
    @Override
    protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        selectedProjectLink = (ProjectLink) getFormComponent().getConvertedInput();
        setResponsePage(selectedProjectLink.getRedirectPage());
    }
}
this.add(projectLinksDropDown);
```

The cool thing with the `AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior` that I am not taking advantage of in my example above is that you can do partial page refresh to hide/show/update panels without having to perform a full page redirect.  Have fun!

Comment: Thanks, it works fine with the AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior. But there are problems with the Links. They shouldn't be added into DropDownChoice in the List, because then the ids of them are missing in the html reference. So instead I just added list of Strings, that are figuring the 'onUpdate' behavior.

Comment: In my example I am assuming that you have a 'ProjectLink' class that maps the text to be displayed by overriding the `#.toString()` method and provides the redirection page in the `#.getRedirectPage()` method.  It sounds like you are determining the redirection page in your onUpdate method, which sounds like it should work fine.  Will you accept & upvote my answer or do you have any further questions?